# Trouble passing through rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to pass this rspec

```
describe "title" do
it "should capitalize the first letter" do
  @book.title = "inferno"
  expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")
end

it "should capitalize every word" do
  @book.title = "stuart little"
  expect(@book.title).to eq("Stuart Little")
end
```

With this code

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(title="")
    @title = capital(title)
  end

  def capital(title)
    articles = %w(the a an and of in the)
    new_title = []

    title.split.each do |w|
      articles.include?(w)? new_title << w : new_title << w.capitalize
      end

    new_title[0] = new_title[0].capitalize
    new_title.join(" ")
  end

end

book = Book.new("stuart little")
puts book.title
```

And I get "Stuart Little" when I run the code, but I keep getting errors when I run it through rspec. (eg, it just returns as "stuart little").

I'm thoroughly confused why this is happening, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only run your `capital` method, when you assign a title to the `new` method, but not when you assign it to the `title=` setter method.

I would replace the `attr_accessor` with a `attr_reader` and add a custom `title=` setter method:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def initialize(title = '')
    self.title = title # calls the setter below
  end

  def title=(title)
    @title = capital(title)
  end

private

  def capital(string)
    articles = %w( a an and in of the )

    words = title.split.map do |word|
      articles.include?(word) ? word : w.capitalize
    end

    words.join(' ').capitalize
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for all my questions, but why is attr_accessor  not enough for a setter that you need a title= setter method? (and thank you for answering!)

Comment: @Stephanie: `attr_accessor` generates a simple setter like `@title = title`. If you used that method it wouldn't call your `capital` method, it would just assign the string without being capitalized before. But if you use the custom `title=` method from my answer, it would assign the change string: `@title = capital(title)`.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help